# Running chefspec on recipes that have dependencies on other cookbooks / libraries erroring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chefspec

I'm working through a few chefspec tutorials and have come up against an issue.

My codebase has a two cookbooks in, with cookbookB being a collection of common methods/libraries that are used by other cookbooks. CookbookA depends on CookbookB and has this defined it the metadata.

The recipes run as intended and achieve the desired result.

When running `chef exec rspec spec` on cookbookA I receive this error:

```
    C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-4.3.5/lib/berkshelf/resolver.rb:85:in `rescue in resolve': Unable to satisfy constraints on packag
e sc_common, which does not exist, due to solution constraint (steve-solr = 0.1.1). Solution constraints that may result in a constraint on sc_common: [(steve-s
olr = 0.1.1) -> (sc_common >= 0.0.0)] (Berkshelf::NoSolutionError)
Missing artifacts: sc_common
Demand that cannot be met: (steve-solr = 0.1.1)
Unable to find a solution for demands: steve-solr (0.1.1)
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-4.3.5/lib/berkshelf/resolver.rb:75:in `resolve'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-4.3.5/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:175:in `install_from_universe'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-4.3.5/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:39:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-4.3.5/lib/berkshelf/berksfile.rb:421:in `install'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-4.3.5/lib/berkshelf/berksfile.rb:630:in `block in vendor'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in `mktmpdir'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-4.3.5/lib/berkshelf/berksfile.rb:628:in `vendor'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chefspec-4.7.0/lib/chefspec/berkshelf.rb:39:in `block in setup!'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:20:in `mute'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chefspec-4.7.0/lib/chefspec/berkshelf.rb:35:in `setup!'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chefspec-4.7.0/lib/chefspec/berkshelf.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:425:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:425:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:357:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1724:in `block in run_hooks_with'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1724:in `each'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1724:in `run_hooks_with'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1679:in `with_suite_hooks'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block in run_specs'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in `report'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:117:in `run_specs'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:93:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
        from C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
PS C:\Users\steve\Dev\steve-solr-restartcores\chef-repos\chef-test\cookbooks\steve-solr> chef exec rspec spec
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32/dl.so: warning: already initialized constant DL::RUBY_FREE
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-3.1.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:16: warning: previous definition of RUBY_FREE was here
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
```

Any help is appreciated as so far my google-fu has failed me.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookbook `sc_common` is not findable from Berkshelf. This shouldn't be related to ChefSpec specifically, if you run `berks install` you should see the same error. You probably need to specify an explicit source for that cookbook if it isn't available in your default source(s).

Comment: thankyou.  I wasn't aware I had berkshelf installed, I don't remember explicitly using it at any point so perhaps theres an issue there - I have a directionin which to look though, thank you! :D

Comment: You set it up via `require 'chefspec/berkshelf'` in your spec helper (probably).